# Difference between 결림 vs 쑤심

Tags: word-usage

Im confused with meaning of 결림. Is it "stabbing pain" (like a needle) or "stiff part of body" (like when every slow move is hard and painful)? Or does it mean both?

Same with 쑤씸. Is it stabbing pain (like a needle) or dull (nagging) pain (like pain in legs after 2 hours running marathon)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Naver dictionary](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/4f335f8b61c94a62a385ba9bbb9db300), "결리다" means:

> 숨을 크게 쉬거나 몸을 움직일 때에, 몸의 어떤 부분이 뜨끔뜨끔 아프거나 뻐근한 느낌이 들다.

I think it's a sudden deep pain that makes it hard for you to move a part of your body.  Personally, I sometimes had it when I was a boy - after sudden sprinting sometimes you'd feel a stabbing pain just beneath your ribs to the side, so much that you could barely walk - I would say "옆구리가 결린다".

[This article](https://www.hankookilbo.com/News/Read/A2020091009090000309) might be helpful:

> 고개를 숙인 자세로 오래 일한 후 어깨 근육에 담이 결렸다고 병원을 찾아오는 분들이 많습니다. 근육이 딱딱하게 뭉쳐지면서 통증을 유발하는 근막통증후군이 아닌가 싶어 근육을 풀어주는 침 주사도 여러 번 맞아봤지만, 그 효과가 오래 가지는 않는다고 합니다.

On the other hand, "쑤시다" is much more generic - the verb originally means "to poke" and move around - e.g., imagine picking your nose, or kids poking a heap of leaves with sticks.  It can mean a dull stabbing pain, or even generic muscle pain or arthritis.  If it's a more acute(?) sense of pain (like poking with a needle), people may say "찌르는 것처럼 아파요."

Disclaimer: I'm not a doctor.  Please don't take these as medical definition.  :P

Answer (score 1):

### “결림”<sub>nominal</sub> ← “결리다”<sub>verb</sub>

> 1. 숨을 크게 쉬거나 몸을 움직일 때에, 몸의 어떤 부분이 뜨끔뜨끔 아프거나 뻐근한 느낌이 들다.
>
> > “갈비뼈가 결리다.”

“결림” (← “결리다”) is *usually* associated with *muscle stiffness*, which gives you somewhat *dull* pain. Though, by definition, it could also mean *sudden sharp* pain (like that you sometimes feel in your chest when you breathe in deep, if you know what I mean.). This is different than “*pins and needles*” (“저림” ← “저리다”).

### “쑤심”<sub>nominal</sub> ← “쑤시다”<sub>verb</sub>

> 1. 신체의 일부분이 바늘로 찌르는 것처럼 아픈 느낌이 들다. (Translation: “to feel like needles are poking part of one’s body.”)
>
> > “머리가 지끈지끈 쑤시다.”

Poking with *needles*? Hmm, actually I’m not sure about this word. I think the focus of this word is not on pain being *sharp*, but it’s more on being *repetitive*. You could use this word to describe kind of *throbbing* pain, *dull* or *sharp*, like migraine. The example sentence is also describing a headache.

---